# What is the wrong with having two SQL update statements

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Question: What might be wrong with the following statements? Write the new SQL .

```
Update table1
set col1= 'XXXXXXXX'
where col2 = 'BBC';

Update table1
set col3 = 123
where col2 = 'BBC';
```

I written new SQL as

```
Update table1
set col1= 'XXXXXXXX', col3 = 123
where col2 = 'BBC', ;
```

However, i am not sure what is the problem of having 2 update statements. Is it to do with exclusive locks?

Thanks all.

Comment: Executnig one query is faster than two.

Comment: How many rows in `table1` have `col2 = 'BBC'`? If it is a large number of rows, you may need to add a `WHERE` clause to make sure you don't update rows that already have the desired values in `col1` and `col3`.

Comment: It's like your mother saying to you: go to the store and buy some milk. So you go and buy milk. Then when you get back she tells you: go to the store and buy some apples. Wouldn't you rather that she told you to buy milk and apples? Saves you a trip.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing *a priori* wrong with having two updates.  Nevertheless, it is not optimal.

Why?  First, it hides your intent.  If the intent is to update a single row, it certainly makes more sense to update both in a single statement.  That is the intention.

Second, two updates take about twice as long.  This would be especially noticeable if the table lacks an index on `col2`.  If they are in the same transaction, then some of the overhead is in the commit.

Also, if each statement is committed individually, the data would be in the intermediate state for a period of time.  Whether that is a problem or not depends on your application.

But, if the intention is to update both at the same time, use a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

In `UPDATE` you could (though a bit simplified) distinct between *three types of costs*:

- accessing the updated row(s)
- locking the updated row(s)
- update cost (evaluating the new value and changing the record)

The first two types are **multiplicated** with each UPDATE statement and can made a *lion share* of the total UPDATE cost (especially if the access is expensive, e.g. FULL TABLE SCAN) or the table is heavily updated (causing waits on LOCKS).

So you definitively **should NOT**

- split an UPDATE of one row in several UPDATE statements and
- UPDATE each row in separate UPDATE statement, if you could use one statement.